# Finding a div content based on attribute value

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Node-red node for integrating with an older ventilation system, using screen scraping, nodejs with cheerio. Works fine for fetching some values now, but I seem unable to fetch the right element in the more complex structured telling which operating mode is active. Screenshot of structure attached. And yes, never used jquery and quite a newbie on cheerio.

I have managed, way to complex, to get the value, if it is within a certain part of the tree.

```
const msgResult = scraped('.control-1');
const activeMode = msgResult.get(0).children.find(x => x.attribs['data-selected'] === '1').attribs['id'];
```

But only works on first match, fails if the data-selected === 1 isn't in that part of the tree. Thought I should be able to use just .find from the top of the tree, but no matches.

```
const activeMode = scraped('.control-1').find(x => x.attribs['data-selected'] === '1')
```

What I would like to get from the html structure attached, is the ID of the div that has data-selected=1, which again can be below any of the two divs of class control-1. Maybe also the content of the underlying span, where the mode is described in text.

[HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiHip.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're looking for but maybe:

```
$('.control-1 [data-selected="1"]').attr('id')
```

Comment: Yes, it kind of works, but for some reason only if "data-selected=1" on the second of the divs that has class=control-1. Data-selected attire is moved based on which mode (div) is activated on the ventilation controller. 
```
 const activeMode = scraped('[data-selected="1"]').attr('id');
``` 
Will find it, but again only on the second div control1.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite follow that.

Comment: Ok, I will try again. In the attached picture, showing the html structure
- One div of class controlh-1, contains to sub divs of class control-1
- both of these control-1 divs contains divs for the different operating modes of the ventilation, given by their ids, ie om1, oc-1 etc. Which one is active is shown by the data-selected=1
- it seems I only get an answer with find if data-selected=1 is in the second of the divs of class control-1

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make some loop to check every tree.

Try this code, hope this works.

```
const cheerio = require ('cheerio')
const fsextra = require ('fs-extra');

(async () => {
    try {

        const parseFile = async (error, contentHTML) => {

            let $ = await cheerio.load (contentHTML)
            const selector = $('.control-1 [data-selected="1"]')

            for (let num = 0; num < selector.length; num++){
                console.log ( selector[num].attribs.id )
            }
        }

        let activeMode = await fsextra.readFile('untitled.html', 'utf-8', parseFile )

    } catch (error) {
        console.log ('ERROR: ', error)
    }
})()
```